# Youtube Requirements Artifacts

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am a Software Engineering student at Universidade de Brasília. I'm developing a project for the subject Software Requirements about the YouTube application. We choose this application to document all related artifacts, functional and non-functional requirements.

We would like to know if the Youtube team could review our progress to collect all the requirements artifacts and give us some tips on how you guys collected the requirements for designing the application.

[Here](https://requisitos-de-software.github.io/2022.1-Youtube/) you can access our Wiki with all the content collected. Or accessing the link below:
https://requisitos-de-software.github.io/2022.1-Youtube/

Thank you so much for the attention.

Answer (score 1):

Only the YouTube team can answer a question this specific. I don't think you'll have great odds of success either way, but you'd be better off [contacting YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/t/contact_us/) than posting on Stackoverflow.

Comment: I tried to contact the developers team there too, but [developers space](https://developers.google.com/youtube) recommends asking a question here with the youtube-api tag.

Comment: @owhenrique everything you are needing to know needs to come from the Youtube group